# How to Get twilio outgoing call sid

Tags: android

I want to get twilio outgoing call sid in  android after the call can be make through server. But in twilio android sdk there is no method to get the response and the code written is in native language. So what is the method to get outgoing call sid in aindroid.

Comment: Actually when call is made then I record that call and to get the recording file I need call sid to dwonload that file.

Comment: As for recording the calls, that is something you can do within the TwiML you set up..

Comment: Everything is working in twiml or server side just i want to get the response on  android side to get the call sid.

Comment: @san if we want to get call sid just after making connection for outgoing call in android,is this statement would give me CALL_SID -> `connection.getParameters().get(Connection.IncomingParameterCallSIDKey);`